# Flex Buttons from string

Tags: string, apache-flex, button

I have buttons with id's button1, button2, button3, etc.

I have a for loop that i need to loop starting with a number and i need to enable buttons based on my loop. I need help taking my string button1 and making that the id "button1" so i can use the button property's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to iterate as such:

```
for (var i:uint = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    var element:IVisualElement = this["group" + i];
}
```

You don't denote whether this Spark or Halo, but clearly substitute IVisualElement with the type of your choice.  (Button, UIComponent, DisplayObject...)